# How do I successfully create a new react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm

**trying:**

```
 npx create-react-app react
```

**getting:**

> Need to install the following packages:
>
> create-react-app
>
> Ok to proceed? (y) y
>
> You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).
>
> We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
>
> Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
>
> - npm uninstall -g create-react-app
> - yarn global remove create-react-app
>
> The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
>
> https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

**following instructions try:**

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**and get**

> up to date, audited 1 package in 217ms
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

Then I try to run the first command again and it never works.

**When I run**

```
npm ls -g --depth 0
```

**I get**

> /usr/local/lib
>
> ├── corepack@0.10.0
>
> ├── nodemon@2.0.12
>
> └── npm@8.1.0

I appreciate any help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

```sh
npx create-react-app@latest my-react-app
#or
npm create react-app@latest my-react-app
```

Comment: wow this worked! Thank you! Can you explain why adding @latest helped?

Comment: I tried just installing `create-react-app` on my machine and it gave me v4.0.3, unless explicitly told to download the latest version. I suppose `npx` does the same. And apparently, there was a security vulnerability found in v4, so they may have blocked its usage entirely.

Answer (score 0):

With new documentation of React

Step 1: Run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Step 2: Run `npm install -g create-react-app`

Step 3: Run `npx create-react-app app-name`